# skip last index of $.each in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/jxzwy4d6/

```
<tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>Education</td>
    <td>abc customer</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>abc@gmail.com</td>
    <td>
        <button class="edit_record">Edit</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

My JS

```
$(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '.edit_record', function (e) {
        $.each($(this).closest('tr'), function (i, obj) {
            //get all td text except last one


        });

    });

});
```

I tried

`if(i != 5){console.log($(this).find('td').text());}` but it doesn't work, the last Edit value is included.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$.each($(this).closest('tr').find('td').not(':last'), function (i, obj) {
    //get all td text except last one
     console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to target the  siblings of the button's parent ... no need to fuss with index this way

```
$('body').on('click', '.edit_record', function (e) {
    $(this).parent().siblings().each(function(){
         console.log( $(this).text() );
     });
});
```

reference [siblings() docs](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Answer (score 2):

Your code will never reach index 5 because, you loop over the `tr` element. Not its `td` element, as table rows only existed 1 element only, use below code :

```
$.each($(this).closest('tr').find('td'), function(i, obj) {
 // i right now having value 0 - 5(this is your last index)
});
```

Updated [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/876ghu14/)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the parent, using `.parent(), .parent('td') or .closest('td')`, of the button and the find the `.siblings`, which will be all `td`s but the one containing the button. And, you can use `.each()` instead of `jQuery.each()`.:

```
  $(this).closest('td').siblings().each(function(i, td) {
      //The last td is excluded here as only the siblings are iterated.
  });
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.edit_record', function() {
      $(this).closest('td').siblings().each(function(i, td) {
          console.log( td );
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>Education</td>
    <td>abc customer</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>abc@gmail.com</td>
    <td>
        <button class="edit_record">Edit</button>
    </td>
</tr>
  </tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgyzp1hf/2/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_record', function() {   
    var table =$(this).closest('tr').find('td:not(:last)');
    table.each(function () {
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
});
```

You can do it this way.Select all td except the last one then iterate on the selected td and get their respective text

Comment: OP is only wanting to target the row where button is, not the whole table. Should also stay with event delegation as it is likely being used for a reason

Comment: @charlietfl sorry i must have misinterpreted the question i just get the value of each td except the last one since the title says `skip last index of $.each in jquery`

Comment: Only because there is one row in table, if there were more than one you would be getting all cells in whole table and have no reference to the row that was selected

Comment: I did make some assumptions though....but that is normally how you would have a table with an edit button within the row is why

Comment: @charlietfl i wan to thank you for clarifying that point you are 100% correct. I gave an incorrect answer because i wasn't paying attention to details.Can you please check i think this will do the trick. I appreciate your critism happy coding